# Repetición en la solución, ¿por qué me sale así?

Tags: python, lista

La idea es que a partir de una lista de listas, que llamaremos "datos" y un número dado ("testigo") pueda devolver otra nueva lista. Esa lista tendría una doble función. Primeramente los números que aparecen en ella reflejarían la cantidad de veces que aparecen en la posición que "testigo" marca en cada sublista, dentro de "datos".

Es complicado, pero poniendo un ejemplo:

funcion("datos","testigo"):

```py
([[2, 15], [1, 21], [3, 3], [3, 77], [1, 50]],0)
```

Para ello debería devolver:

```py
Usando el testigo 0:
El número 1 aparece 2 veces
El número 2 aparece 1 vez
El número 3 aparece 2 veces
```

El problema radica en que me saca el programa otra cosa distinta:

```py
Usando el testigo  0 : 
 El número 0 aparece 2 veces
 El número 0 aparece 2 veces
 El número 1 aparece 2 veces
 El número 0 aparece 2 veces
 El número 1 aparece 2 veces
 El número 2 aparece 2 veces
 El número 0 aparece 2 veces
 El número 1 aparece 2 veces
 El número 2 aparece 2 veces
 El número 3 aparece 2 veces
 El número 0 aparece 2 veces
 El número 1 aparece 2 veces
 El número 2 aparece 2 veces
 El número 3 aparece 2 veces
 El número 4 aparece 2 veces
```

Lo que tengo hecho sería algo así, no sé qué me puede faltar:

```py
def funcion(datos, testigo):
    res=1
    lista=[]

    print("Usando el testigo ", testigo,": ")
    for l in datos:
        lista.insert(l[testigo],res+1)

        for i in range(len(lista)):

            s=" El número {0} aparece {1} veces"
            print(s.format(i,lista[i]))
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu implementación está mal por varias razones:

1. No está contando realmente cuántas veces aparece cada número, pues tienes un solo contador "común" (la variable `res`), que no depende de qué número estés procesando. Necesitas un contador diferente para cada número.
2. El contador `res` que has implementado no cambia nunca de valor. Lo inicializas con `res=1` y así se queda, y luego vas insertando en la lista el valor `res+1`, que naturalmente es siempre `2`.
3. El bucle en que imprimes las cosas está anidado dentro del bucle general. Así que para cada iteración del bucle `for l in datos`, vuelves a ejecutar completamente el bucle interno `for i in range(len(lista))`. Entiendo que la misión de este bucle interno era mostrar los resultados, por lo que tendría que ir fuera del otro bucle, una vez todos los datos hayan sido procesados.

   Al meterlo dentro, imprimes la lista completa cada vez que el bucle externo se ejecuta. En la primera iteración la lista tiene un solo elemento, la segunda tiene dos, la tercera tiene tres, etc. Por eso te sale "El número 0", después "El número 0" y "El número 1", después "El número 0", "El número 1" y "El número 2", etc... Y para todos ellos el contador es 2 por la razón explicada en el punto anterior.

El enfoque no es apropiado.

- Por un lado, la idea de hacer un `insert()` en la lista según el dato que encuentres en `l[testigo]` no funcionará si el primer dato que encuentras es por ejemplo 2 en vez de 0, ya que en ese caso no puedes insertar aún en la posición 2 por estar la lista vacía. Es decir, tu `insert()` sólo funciona mientras los datos que encuentres sean 0, 1, 2... en este orden.
- Por otro lado como dije antes necesitas un contador separado para cada dato que vayas encontrando.

Ambos problemas se resuelven si mantienes un *diccionario* (en vez de una lista) en el que las claves sean los datos que vas encontrando, y sus valores los respectivos contadores. Así añadirías `diccionario[dato]=1` la primera vez que encuentres uno, o harías `diccionario[dato]+=1` las veces siguientes para incrementar ese contador.

Por otro lado, para que el diseño del programa sea más limpio y genérico, mejor hacer que la función se limite a calcular ese diccionario y devolverlo como resultado, y que sea el programa principal quien se ocupe de imprimir el resultado. De este modo la misma función te servirá para otros cometidos en los que no quieras ver el resultado por pantalla, sino por ejemplo guardarlo en disco, etc.

Así:

```
def funcion(datos, testigo):
    contadores = {}   # Diccionario inicialmente vacío
    for l in datos:
        dato = l[testigo]
        if dato not in contadores:  # Si es la primera vez que lo vemos
            contadores[dato] = 1
        else:
            contadores[dato] += 1
    return contadores


testigo = 0
datos = [[2, 15], [1, 21], [3, 3], [3, 77], [1, 50]]
resultado = funcion(datos, testigo)
print("Usando el testigo {}".format(testigo))
for n in sorted(resultado):
    print("El dato {} aparece {} veces".format(n, resultado[n]))
```

Al ejecutarlo sale:

```
Usando el testigo 0
El dato 1 aparece 2 veces
El dato 2 aparece 1 veces
El dato 3 aparece 2 veces
```

## Otra solución

Python ya viene con muchas funciones de utilidad para la mayoría de problemas habituales. Y contar cuántas veces aparece cada dato en una lista es un problema habitual, que se puede resolver con `collections.Counter()`. Basta pasarle como parámetro la lista cuyos elementos queremos contar, que podemos construir haciendo una *expresión generadora* sobre tus datos de entrada, que se quede con el elemento deseado en cada sub-lista (indicado por `testigo`).

Con este enfoque tu `funcion()` quedaría tan simple como:

```
from collections import Counter
def funcion2(datos, testigo):
    return Counter(l[testigo] for l in datos)
```